# python request.get always throws status code 200

Tags: python

python request.get always throws status code 200 . This is coming even after adding an user agent in the request.get( ) .
As status_code is always 200 , a file from that website is downloaded even if doesn't exists there . 
How to get correct atatus_code ?

Comment: So what do you think a HTTP status code of 200 mean?

Comment: 200 means OK, as in it worked, you want it to fail?

Comment: I am using request.get().status_code for further processing , the url inside has a file , on non working days file doesn't exists , so status_code is 404 for those days . But now i am getting status_code as 200 always and a file is downloaded for non working days too ,  although the file is garbage . So I want exact status_code from request.get().

Comment: As people have pointed out, I really think you should read up on [HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and adjust your expectations and handle the different status codes accordingly. And update your question with the details you just mentioned in the comments, because the question is quite vague without those details. Answer this in your question: What's the epected status code, why, and what are you recieving now and what isn't working.

Comment: the website was working fine ,  but from today is not throwing data for download by python automation , so I added User agent inside request.code() , but now it throws 200 always for all the days . So no way to handle an exception .I think the website has found way to block a mass download by python automation .

Answer (score 0):

`200` - "The HTTP 200 OK success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded."  This means it worked! Now, on to the next steps... :)

Comment: I am using request.get().status_code for further processing , the url inside has a file , on non working days file doesn't exists , so status_code is 404 for those days . But now i am getting status_code as 200 always and a file is downloaded for non working days too , although the file is garbage . So I want exact status_code from request.get().

Comment: @Ajit you need to check if the "file is garbage", because if a request with 200 (OK) code is sent, you can't get another code with requests.

Comment: Fix whatever is producing this "garbage" and putting it on the web server, because apparently **something** is send from the server to your script…

Comment: now is Sunday , a non working day , but still I am getting a file , as the content inside that file is a real garbage ,  and the content of the file itself goes to bid data set ,  the content has to to be exact order .

Comment: @Ajit think how to distinguish "garbage" and a normal file. What are the features of the "normal" file?

Comment: @Demian , a normal file is this case a csv file has exact matrix of row and columns 5 * 20, which is input to another file . a Garbage file is something that gives to not relevant data for that day . Its a stock market data , I think the website I am using has find a way to desists python automaton that downloads mass data .

Comment: @Ajit then you can only try to trick the site by changing User-Agent etc. (maybe that counts).